# OOPS! Schengen overstay,

Tags: schengen, overstaying

Several visits to Schengen in 2017.  Due to arithmetic error, totals more than 90 days.  U.S. citizen.

Don't want to brag about it—"You didn't catch me, needed,neener,neener!"

But I'd like to have with me on the next visit something(s) to pull out in case I get confronted with it.  What sort of thing should I prepare?  Should I add the amount of overstay to the ninety days of absence?  Or to the 180 days from first entrance?

Or to put it another way, what could a person obtain/prepare/present to avoid problems **after** an unintentional overstay?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You arrive, they say you overstayed, and you present them with what exactly? What purpose do you hope for this document to achieve? If there was some kind of unavoidable reason for your overstay (say, hospitalization), then documentation for that could be helpful, but that's seemingly not the case here.

Comment: Also, are you saying that the total duration of your visits is over 90 days, or that one of your visits was over 90 days?

Comment: I think you should use a Schengen days counter. https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm And read related questions and answer on this site, we have quite a few. Search for Schengen day counter or something like that. You may have overstayed, or you may just have made one more mistake and are still within the limits.

Comment: Whether an arithmetic error is unavoidable is debatable.  :-). The purpose of the undefined document/application/whatever is to prevent a permanent ban without several kilograms of paperwork.  I planned my exit for the third trip to make the total less than 90 but afterward I recomputed and it is over a hundred.  You ask I present them with what exactly, but that is only repeating my question.

Comment: Well, that calculator is nice.  Too late now, though!

Comment: @jcaron: "totals more than 90 days"

Comment: The only thing to do is to apply for a Schengen. I don't see any other fruitful way, sorry

Comment: Apply for a Schengen?  You mean a visa?  One of the other articles said U.S. citizens cannot apply for a Schengen visa.  Most of the ones that came up in the search were irrelevant, but I am getting the impression that the safest thing might be to find an official who's a "nice guy," confess to the accident, pay the fine and get some sort of document from him.

Comment: Seems clear enough to me.

Comment: Can you wait more than three months before going back?

Comment: @phoog: I don't have a particular schedule to return.  But whenever it is, I don't want to be turned away and/or put on some sort of blacklist.

Comment: I recently had a Spanish border official ask "How can you be arriving when you already arrived?"  He saw an entry stamp for a plane change and didn't see the next day's exit stamp on the same passport page.  And when I applied for NIE, they accused me of an overstay and told me to get out, over a similar oversight.